# jQuery change class when first character in input field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a script to change a credit card image based on the first character in an input field.

I'm able to capture the first character without any problem, but when I set up my conditions the first if statement if showing as true regardless of what character is entered.

I've created a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/jp05dv35/). There's some console logs added that show the first character correctly being captured, but the first condition always triggers as true.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Credit Card Number</label>
      <input class="credit-card" type="text"/><i class="fa"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-group').on('click',function(){
        $(this).find('label').addClass('moveUp');
    });
    $('.credit-card').keyup(function(){
        var firstChar = $(this).val().charAt(0);

        console.log(firstChar)

        if ($(firstChar === 4)) {
            console.log('yup, you got a four');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa-cc-visa active');
        } else if ($(firstChar === 5)) {
            console.log('yup, you got a five');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa-cc-mastercard active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa');
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle with working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/jp05dv35/2/)

Comment: You also want to compare against a string ... `firstChar === "5"` e.g.

Comment: Good call - I'll throw that in as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any html input's value provided to JavaScript is a string by default. Since you use the strict [JavaScript compare operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), you need to provide a string on the right side of your compare statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-group').on('click',function(){
        $(this).find('label').addClass('moveUp');
    });
    $('.credit-card').keyup(function(){
        var firstChar = $(this).val().charAt(0);

        console.log(firstChar)

        if (firstChar === "4") {
                      //  ^ removes `$(..)` and add string compare
            console.log('yup, you got a four');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa-cc-visa active');
        } else if (firstChar === "5") {
            console.log('yup, you got a five');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa-cc-mastercard active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fa-cc-visa {
  background-color: red;
}

.fa-cc-mastercard {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Credit Card Number</label>
      <input class="credit-card" type="text"/><i class="fa">C</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I changed above is that now I'm comparing two strings instead of a string and a number.

Answer (score 4):

There should be no `$()` wrapper in the condition:

```
if (firstChar === "4") {
```

The other condition should be fixed as well.

---

**Edit:** as it has been pointed out by **drinchev** in the comment, you also want to change the comparison in the condition itself. You can either maintain the strict equality and use `=== "4"` to compare string against a string, or you could try with typecasting equality by using `== 4` (double equality sign instead of triple one). I would recommend the first one.

Comment: Geez - I feel stupid on that one, but good eye. That's definitely it!

Comment: @mdziekon your code actually [does not work](https://jsbin.com/qarokesalu/edit?html,js,console,output). You need to compare strings not numbers.

Comment: Haven't noticed that, but still the main problem was with the ``$()`` wrapper, strict equation should be much of a problem once the first one was solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the var type.

Another thing when you change values ​​from 4 to 5 or 5 to 4 without using backspace or delete, you have to clear the class before adding a new class.

Look i converted the value to string.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dc7tpLL/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-group').on('click',function(){
        $(this).find('label').addClass('moveUp');
    });
    $('.credit-card').keyup(function(){
        var firstChar = $(this).val().charAt(0);



        if (String(firstChar) === "4") {
      $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa fa-cc-visa active');
        } else if (String(firstChar) == "5") {

      $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa');
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').addClass('fa-cc-mastercard active');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.fa').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa');
        }
    });
});
```